Why does Partial<Record<string, string>> not extends Record<string, string>
type Check<T> = T extends Record<string, string> ? true : false

type T1 = Check<{ id: string }> // true
type T2 = Check<Partial<{ id: string }>> // true

type T3 = Check<Record<string, string>> // true
type T4 = Check<Partial<Record<string, string>>> // false

It seems undefined that makes Partial<Record<string, string>> not satisfy Record<string, string>, but why Partial<{ id: string }> satisfies?

What is the point of saying Partial<Record<string, string>>, Record<string, string> is already enough to say that properties are optional, but if they exist, they must be a string.
type Partial<Record<string, string>> is equivalent to saying Record<string, string | undefined>

• Record<string, X> is the index signature {[k: string]: X}, so that's the feature whose behavior you care about. • TS doesn't have "optional index signatures" (see ms/TS#46969 so that's the discrepancy. Partial<Record<string, X>> becomes {[k: string]: X | undefined}, there's no {[k: string]?: X} to speak of.  Two index signatures that differ by undefined are incompatible, but optional properties are assignable to required ones regardless of undefined. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Thanks to both of you for your help. I kind of figured it out.

You know, the more I look a this the more I think there might be a bug allowing, say, {a?: string} to be assignable to {[k: string]: string}. Maybe I'll file one in GitHub and come back here.
